# Swapping columns in FasterCSV::Table

Tags: ruby, csv, fastercsv

I have almost 1000+ CSV files where I need to shuffle several columns and recreate each CSV file with the shuffled columns. As an example, initial CSV file has "H1", "H2" and "H3" columns. The new CSV file will have columns "H1", "H3" and "H2".

Using FasterCSV in Ruby how would I do it? I have tried `FasterCSV::Table` with `column_name` access but no luck.

Can some kind soul help?

Regards

K

Answer (score 1):

It's not too complicated:

```
CSV.open('new.csv', 'w') do |new_csv|
    CSV.foreach('old.csv') do |row|
        row[1], row[2] = row[2], row[1]
        new_csv << row
    end
end
```

I call it CSV instead of FasterCSV because that's the 1.9 way

Comment: Thanks a million. Yes it is simple indeed.